# How can I disable the default keyboard and enable my keyboard in my app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

In my application, some EditText are created dynamically. I would like to disable the Android keyboard by default on every EditText, and enable my keyboard. How can I disable the default keyboard and enable my keyboard in my app?

Answer (score 0):

The user can *elect* to switch to your input method editor (either via Settings, a long-press in an `EditText`, etc.), but you cannot *force* the user to switch to your input method editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClickListener(){

  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EDIT_TEXT_FIELD.getWindowToken(), 0);

  //Display your key here

}
```